# Deploy vaadin 7 addon/widget set into OSGI enabled application on Glassfish server

Tags: osgi, vaadin

I am trying to add vaadin calender addon into OSGI enabled application from last 7 days. Can some tell me the steps or guide me to achieve this ? Is there any kind of OSGI compatible vaadin addon that can be added like a plain jar ?

Any help is appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using some vaadin addons on Vaadin 7 AND OSGi.

To do this, I've created a custom widgetset as a fragment bundle of the Vaadin Web Application. This widgetset have's the client-side of all needed addons. Latter, you will need to OSGi-fy the Addon server part, and it it as any normal bundle. Im using BND-tools (command line) to do that.